# Use javascript on embedded site? (iframe, object)

Tags: javascript, html, object, iframe

This is what I have tried, couple of other things too, no luck.

This too, `document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].submit();`

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function click()
        {
        $('#myiframe').document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].submit();
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        
        <body>
        <iframe id="myiframe" src="http://google.com"></iframe> 
        
        <button type="button" onClick="click()">Logg inn</button>
        <object type="text/html" data="http://google.no" width="100%" height="1000px"></object>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: There is no element(s) with the name btnK? And you can't submit a button, only a form can submit.

Comment: google page can't be loaded in a frame. Try another page

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Do you want someone to load your bank account in an iframe on some random page and start clicking buttons? No, that is why this security measure is in place.

Comment: I can write "javascript:document.getEle..." in the address bar in chrome and it works.

So shouldnt there be a way? redirect the iframe to a "javascript:document.getEle..." code?

Comment: No, address bar and console is not same as a web page with an iframe in it.